# loading Image from QUrl with blackberry 10

Tags: image, blackberry-10, qurl

```
bb::cascades::Image m_image = Image(QUrl(appRoot +"default.png"));
```

If the file does not exist what m_image returns ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should return *null*

> One of the benefits of packaging an image with the application is that
>   it allows the tool to verify the images and optimize them for the
>   devices they are targeting. Because they are packaged with the
>   application, it should be assumed that they are instantly available,
>   and should never fail to load. **If an incorrect name is provided when
>   an asset is created, an null image is returned.**

[Image documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__Image.html)